# How to detect industrial camera?

Tags: c#, camera, computer-vision, emgucv, aforge

I been trying to develop a software in C# to connect to the USB camera. It is an industrial camera from Toshiba with the model BU238B. I had try using machine vision library such as AForge and EmguCV to connect with it. However, when I run the code it only shows non-industrial camera (such as my own Webcam) in the list, meanwhile the industrial camera can't be detected. I had check on my device manager (no problem with the connection between my PC and the industrial camera)and downloaded the right driver for the camera. Please, anyone would kindly help me to solve the problem?

```
private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevice; // camera list
        private VideoCaptureDevice Final_Frame; // camera frame

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            disconnectbtn.Enabled = false;
            sendbtn.Enabled = false;
            Connectbtn.Enabled = true;
            CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);   // here store all the device connected into "CaptureDevice"
            foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)//add all connected device into the camera list box
            {
                cmbcamera.Items.Add(Device.Name); 
            }
            cmbcamera.SelectedIndex = 0; //make default selection as the first device found
            Final_Frame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
        }

private void strbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Final_Frame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[cmbcamera.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);// selected device will connect once start button been press
            Final_Frame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Final_Frame_NewFrame);// camera connected keep on track with latest event, if no this code the camera will not update to latest event
            Final_Frame.Start(); // start camera
        }
```

Comment: Well, what does the camera documentation say? The official libraries? The camera software?
How to open a camera does not depend on aforge or emgu, but on the libraries for the camera support

Comment: Hi, I just read through the documentation again, now i may understand why i cant detect the camera. Thanks a lot.
But I encounter a problem that the sample code in the documentation for the camera is all written in C++, does this mean that I should develop the software in C++?
Is it possible for me to continue develop the software in C#?

Comment: Not necessarily. It _might_ be easier, but also, C# can interop with C++ DLLs.

Comment: @ADyson thks a lot for your reply, appreciate it .

Comment: A reasonable guess would be that the camera uses the GigE/USB3 vision protocol. There are multiple SDKs available for this, both first and third party, including some that has .Net wrappers. Search for "usb3 vision .net sdk" and you should get some alternatives.

Comment: Do you have the vendors drive for camera installed?  Check Device manager.  You should be able to enumerate through the USB deice to find camera.  Depending on the USB device you may need to check different parameters to find device.  Some do not have a type but instead you can find the name.